# How to simulate buy/sell to know taxes like honeypot.is does?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, bsc

I am trying to know how much tax on sell and buy are needed before buy. How can I do that in nodejs ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.